# x=x+y gives different result from x=+y

Tags: python

I am creating a function to compose cummulative density fuction (cdf) based on the dictionary of probabilities
I face a strange problem of x=x+y performing differently from x=+y

Consider

```
orgs_pdf= {"Sales":0.2,
       "Marketing":0.2,
       "IT":0.3,
       "Manufacturing":0.25,
       "Finances":0.05
        }
```

Variant 1:

```
   def cdf(pdf):
        result={}
        cummdens=0
        total=sum(pdf.values())
            for n in pdf:
                cummdens=cummdens+pdf[n]/total
                result[n]=cummdens
        return result
    print(cdf(orgs_pdf))
```

Output 1:

```
{'Sales': 0.2, 'Marketing': 0.4, 'IT': 0.7, 'Manufacturing': 0.95, 'Finances': 1.0}
```

This output is as expected

Variant 2:

```
def cdf(pdf):
    result={}
    cummdens=0
    total=sum(pdf.values())
    for n in pdf:
        cummdens=+pdf[n]/total
        result[n]=cummdens
    return result

print(cdf(orgs_pdf))
```

Output 2:

```
{'Sales': 0.2, 'Marketing': 0.2, 'IT': 0.3, 'Manufacturing': 0.25, 'Finances': 0.05}
```

The output just reproduces orgs_pdf dictionary

The only difference in two functions is that I use `cummdens=cummdens+pdf[n]/total` in the first and `cummdens=+pdf[n]/total` in the second, which theoretically are supposed to work the same way, but they don't. any ideas why?

Comment: `x=+y` is saying "`x` equals the result of `+y`". You meant `x += y`.

Comment: You meant: `cummdens+=pdf[n]/total` and not: `cummdens=+pdf[n]/total`

Comment: History lesson of the day: in the [B language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)), a precursor to C, the syntax *was* `=+` rather than `+=`. C kept the operation but changed the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

`x+=y` means "x = x + y".

`x=+y` means "x = the positive value of y".

Just as you can do `x = -3`, you can do `x = +3`.  Likewise, `x=-y` and `x=+y`.

It's an easy mistake to make.  :)